# What is this format for post method for form?

Tags: html, node.js, post, onsubmit

I saw this code on the internet, and I'm a little puzzled of what it does, particularly on the onsubmit portion.

```
  <form id="generateForm" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return writeForm(event);">
```

Am I correct to assume that the onsubmit portion essentially runs writeForm method. The writeForm method then returns some value (ex. string) and then post sends it to where action is pointing to (#). If I'm not mistakent # means it isn't being sent anywhere.

On another point, how would I even grab that value in nodejs? Say it does what I think it does and sends for example a string representing an xml file, I don't think I can do something like in nodejs.

```
var recievedString = req.body.stringID
```

Comment: You're correct.  Basically, JavaScript is being used to handle the form instead.  If JavaScript doesn't run and cancel the submit event, the form data will effectively go nowhere.

Comment: Ah thankyou so much. However, I forgot to add another point, do you know the answer to it?

Comment: Node.js is completely irrelevant.  This code is entirely client-side.  Now, the code in `writeForm` might make some call to your server, but you didn't post that code, so who knows what happens.

Comment: I found this code online, so I don't know what writeForm is either. You mentioned that the code is entirely client side. Is that because action is equal to #? if I make it go to something like app.js, will it then move it to the server?

Comment: Only if you get rid of the `onsubmit` attribute as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct to assume that the onsubmit portion essentially runs writeForm method.

Yes.

> The writeForm method then returns some value (ex. string)

Yes.

> and then post sends it to where action is pointing to (#)

No.

If the value returned by the onsubmit function is a true value, then it will submit the form as normal. It it returns a false value, then it will prevent the form from submitting.

> If I'm not mistakent # means it isn't being sent anywhere.

No. The relative URL `#` is a reference to the top of the page. Using it as a form action doesn't really make sense since a new page load will be triggered anyway. It will just submit to the URL of the current page.