# For a form submit button, is it possible to edit form input with some client side javascript before being sent to app.js (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

So currently, I have a form with many parameters and a button that when clicked causes the user inputs to be edited into a more manageable string. Is it possible to at the same time send it to my Nodejs server and if so how to get that value (I'm guessing something like req.body.generateForm but I doubt that works)? This is the basic structure of my form.

```
 <form id="generateForm" method="post" action="/app" onsubmit="return writeForm(event);">
```

Comment: If you edit the value, then you've edited it and that is the value that will be submitted. You should provide a [mcve]. (If you're just going to perform string manipulation on data to make it more manageable, then you would be better off doing it on the server though, that's an environment where you can guarantee that the JS won't be bypassed or fail due to browser settings).

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I'm new with web development so I try to do most of my work client side. Your answer seemed to contradict with Brad's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51103608/what-is-this-format-for-post-method-for-form .

Comment: As Brad said, we have no idea what the `writeForm` function does. If your function prevents the form from submitting, and you want to send the data to the server, then you should change it so it doesn't stop the form from submitting!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, instead of attaching your function directly on the form via onsubmit and calling it. You can instead add an event listener and prevent default.

adding event listener

```
let form = document.querySelector("#generateForm");
form.addEventListener("submit", writeForm, true);
```

more about event listenders here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

```
function writeForm(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //your function to mutate and send data here...
}
```

i advise you practise sending data using vanilla javascript once, just to know how it works. then using ajax Jquery to make it easier. lastly moving forward using a webframework to really simplifly things.

FYI, i found MDN web docs to be a great resource.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was a lot more useful. However, what do you mean prevent default? I assume from your steps of adding an event listener instead of an onsubmit would allow POST to send the modified string to app.js?

Comment: the event object is automatically passed as a first argument once called, and it contains default methods you can call. One of which is preventDafault which stops the event from continuing. better explanation and sample code here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault